# Will the force on the output piston be bigger than the force on the input piston in a confined container?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Suppose we have a confined container with two pistons on both sides filled with a fluid. Now we know that,
$F_1/F_2 =A_1/A_2$
Let's say that $F_1$ is the input force.
Now $F_2$ should be the input force times the ratio of the two areas of the pistons.

Question: Will the output force (or the force acting on the output piston) always be greater than the input force?

Comment: Depends on the ratio of two areas. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem statement is incorrect. F1 must equal F2. You are probably thinking of pressures being proportional to area.  A picture would help

Comment: @RC_23, I think you've got it backward. The pressure is what must be equal everywhere within the vessel (if we ignore gravity and the density of the fluid.) The force on the two pistons is what's proportional to their areas. That's what the OP's equation, $F_1/F_2=A_1/A_2$, asserts.

Comment: Re, "Will output force...always be greater...?" No. Like your equation says, the forces are proportional to the areas of the pistons. Whichever _piston_ is bigger will experience the greater force. It doesn't matter which one you choose to call "input" and which you call "output."

Comment: Ok, I may have been visualizing it wrong, what was written.  I was thinking similar to a gas booster (single stage), i.e.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_pump#Gas_pressure

Comment: Your relationship applies only at equilibrium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_2 = \frac{F_1A_2}{A_1}$

so if $A_2$ is smaller than $A_1$ the output force is less than the input force.